# Regex for latitude with required 6 decimal places

Tags: java, regex, string, double

I need a regex in Java that will check if a *String* representation of a *double* has required 6 decimal places. Before the decimal point, value can be positive or negative.

```
1.123456 - correct
-123123123.123456 - correct
123123123.123456 - correct
-123123123.123456 - correct

1.12345 - wrong
-.123456 - wrong
.123456 - wrong
.12345 - wrong
123456 - wrong
```

I tried:

```
^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(\.\d{6})?\s*$
```

but it doesn't cover all edges.

Comment: If you require 6 decimal places, why have you made decimal places optional?

Comment: Immediately I can imagine an edge case here.  What happens if a lat/lng value only has 4 digits, because everything from the fifth digit onward is known to be zero and does not appear?  Then, would you still require 6 digits always?

Comment: The *double* type and "decimal places" are two concepts which (perhaps surprisingly) have basically nothing to do with each others. Perhaps instead of double you mean string containing decimal number? Converting between that and *double* value is lossy operation.

Comment: Is the double a "double string"? It is not clear whenever the double is a double string or a double literal.

Comment: Furthermore, what counts as "correct" and "wrong" in your question? You should give your current and expected results to support the "correctness" and "wrongness" of these digit strings. The question has been downvoted so urgent attention is required.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
^\s*(-|\+)?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{6}\s*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/nfJdiHx2sE).

This allows the first digits to be zero *only if* it's the only digit before the dot, eg `0.123456` is OK, but not `01.123456`. `\.\d{6}` requires exactly 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

The valid input should

- start with optional whitespaces --->`^\s*`
- then optional `-` or `+`--->`(-|\+)?`
- then one or multiple digits--->`\d+`
- then one dot ---> `.`
- then six digits --->`(\d{6})`
- end with optional whitespaces --->`^\s*`

Try this:

```
^\s*(-|\+)?\d+\.(\d{6})\s*$
```

Answer (score 2):

In your regex the positive lookahead `(?=.*[1-9])` asserts that what is on the right side should contain a digit which will succeed for all examples. After that assertion you match zero or more digits `\d*` followed by a part that optionally matches a dot and 6 digits `(\.\d{6})?` so this will match `.588888` or also `1`.

If you want to match an optional minus sign you could use `-?`

For your example data you might use:

[`^-?\d+\.\d{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/BrfE5c/1)

In Java:

```
String regex = "^-?\\d+\\.\\d{6}$";
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `-?` Match an optional minus sign
- `\d+\.\d{6}` Match one or more digits, a dot and 6 digits
- `$` Assert the end of the line

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DQUD44717)